# Is Displayed for multiple elements giving error: Permission denied to access property "_wrapped"

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

The code I tried:

```
//Resolve a particular URL
List<WebElement> fields  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<xpath>")); //find multiple elements and store into array list.

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(fields));
```

**The exception I receive:**

> Permission denied to access property "_wrapped" Build info: version:
>   '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' System
>   info: host: '207-254-7-224', ip: '207.254.7.224', os.name: 'windows',
>   os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver
>   info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, language=Ruby,
>   browserstack.selenium.jar.version=3.0.1, appBuildId=20161104212021,
>   moz:firefoxOptions={args=[],
>   profile=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},
>   resolution=1024x768, platform=XP, specificationLevel=0,
>   acceptSslCerts=false, processId=4596, browser=firefox,
>   browserVersion=50.0, platformVersion=6.1, acceptSslCert=false,
>   XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, browser_version=50.0, platformName=windows_nt,
>   64bit=true, browserstack.debug=true, rotatable=false, os=Windows,
>   browserstack.ie.noFlash=false, os_version=7, firefoxOptions={args=[],
>   profile=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},
>   version=50.0, proxy={}, command_id=1, firefox_binary=c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\firefox 50.0\firefox.exe, browserstack.video=true, orig_os=win7,
>   takesElementScreenshot=true,
>   firefox_profile=UEsDBBQAAAAIADNwWUmK7I+M9AMAA..., proxy_type=node}]
>   Session ID: 0c6443f1-43a1-4441-b022-05be88e202ed

**Findings:**

Occurs only on `Firefox v50`. Tested locally as well as on Cloud infrastructures like `BrowserStack`.

Is this a known issue on Firefox v50? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue.

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7931

The workaround posted in that thread is to put a `try-catch` around the call. The call seems to work but it throwing unnecessarily for some reason. I haven't used this myself but at least one other user in the thread claimed it worked for them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox 47, I'm trying to investigate this issue and ask/rise ticket where it should be. 
All firefox above 47 have this problem, on all selenium between 2.4-3.4, gecko driver 1.4-1.6.1.

More info: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/438

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced with all Geckodriver and selenium-webdriver above version 3 when using `execute_script`.

I switch back to selenium-webdriver-2.53.4 and and using the firefox driver. Then the issue went out.