# Firefox driver Permission denied to access property "_wrapped"

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, browserstack

I am getting the following error while waiting for waiting for the element to be present.

**Code**

```
return self.wait(timeout, driver).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, locator_value)))
```

**Firefox Version:** 53.0 and 52.0

**Selenium Version:** 3.4.0

It works perfectly with **49.0 version.**

Browsestack Capabilities

> "browser": "Firefox", 
>   "browserVersion": "", 
>   "os": "Windows",
>   "osVersion": "7", 
>   "resolution": "1024x768", 
>   "marionette": true

**Error:**

> Error: Permission denied to access property "_wrapped" Build info:
>   version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info:
>   host: '185-44-131-246', ip: '185.44.131.246', os.name: 'windows',
>   os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver
>   info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{moz:profile=C:\Windows\proxy\rust_mozprofile.WHqBtiZRRUrH,
>   rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0,
>   script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY,
>   specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false,
>   acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=6.1,
>   moz:processID=3832.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID:
>   e4e0d3d6-c9ca-478c-bb58-b1ec2fa9317c

**update:**

The problem is with is_displayed method, it's not supported. However, it happens only with some html framework, I tried the same code on google website and it works. However on our application which is using react framework it fails with above problem.

More weird thing. It works with Selenium **3.0.1 beta2** and Firefox 49,51,52 for atleast is **is_displayed** method, however it gives same error for mouse events (ActionChains) and JavaScript Execution.

Comment: I am also seeing this.  Firefox 53.0.2 (64-bit).  MacOS 10.12.4 (16E195)  Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)  geckodriver 0.16.1

Comment: If you are seeing the error on BrowserStack then you should see the same on Firefox locally on your machine. Regarding mouse move actions, I tried this locally on Firefox and it works when just using GeckoDriver 0.16. It fails if I introduce the selenium jar 3.x (http://localhost:4444/wd/hub), not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Ticket rised here :
[Is Displayed for multiple elements giving error: Permission denied to access property "_wrapped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165884/is-displayed-for-multiple-elements-giving-error-permission-denied-to-access-pro)

Use Firefox 47 as version above have this issues.

More info: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/438